# R unexpected symbol error on opening in ubuntu

Tags: r

I am getting this problem on startup with R on an Ubuntu server:

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing"
Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Error: 1:4: unexpected symbol
1: et default
```

I tried a new install and the problem persists. The same things happens when trying to install a package:

```
trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/src/contrib/HMMpa_1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 36272 bytes (35 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 35 Kb

Error: 1:4: unexpected symbol
1: et default
   ^
Execution halted

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmphumgi9/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
```

Comment: The problem seems to be with `liblapack`. Check the required version of this library required to compile R and then recompile. Also check that if that library is loaded in your system.

Comment: I managed to fix this part of the problem by uninstalling `libopenblas-base`. However, the `et default` error did not resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `unexpected symbol` problem was due to broken code in my `.Rprofile`. Solution found here: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Error-on-Startup-Error-7-6-unexpected-symbol-7-set-the-td4448600.html